# querystring drop down menu mvc asp.net selected item list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selected

i want to write query string if conditions = 2

i have drop down menu in this menu i have position which is {main , left ,up, bottom}
if i wrote in my locl host localhost:27593  admin  item   create?type=2
should in position just i see left and main 
in asp.net and mvc  i want to write code right plz help me

```
 public ActionResult Create (int? id)
    {
        //querystring
        // 2 ise

       int TYPEE = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["typee"] );
          string[] separateURL = url.Split('?');
         NameValueCollection queryString = 
                    System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(separateURL[1]) ;
        if (TYPEE == 2)
       {
          SelectListItem[] items = new SelectListItem[2];
           items[0] = new SelectListItem"main" ,"1");
           items[1] = new SelectListItem("left" , "2");
           DropDownList1.Items.AddRange(items);
           DropDownList1.DataBind();
       }
       else
       {
          SelectListItem[] items = new  SelectListItem[5];
           items[0] = new  SelectListItem("main", "1");
           items[1] = new  SelectListItem("left", "2");
           items[2] = new  SelectListItem("right", "3");
           items[3] = new  SelectListItem("top", "4");
           items[3] = new  SelectListItem("bottom", "5");

           DropDownList1.Items.AddRange(items);

           DropDownList1.DataBind();
           return View();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use?

```
public ActionResult Create (int type, int? id)
```

That way the default model binder will bind the value of type from the query string to the variable type.

EDIT:

I've just seen a typo also, you are looking for 'typee' key in the QueryString collection, however there is no such key in it, only the 'type' key is in it.

```
int TYPEE = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["type"])
```